# RStudio and Knit: Unable to display latex fonts

Tags: r, chromium, knitr, rstudio, mathjax

When I knit a document to HTML, I get the following error messages:

```
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/imageFonts.js
File failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:37362/html_preview/mathjax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/imageFonts.js

Loading Web-Font TeX/Math/Italic
File failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:37362/html_preview/mathjax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/png/imagedata.js
```

I am also unable to view it Rpubs view internet browser.

I've tried reinstalling knitr, mathjax fonts, etc. Still unable to see latex math.

I'm using xubuntu.

NOTE: Viewing the converted HTML file directly in chromium and firefox works fine, however.

Comment: How about a minimal working example and session info?